# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape data and not getting all rows

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rows

I am new to Python and coding in general. I 95% there and the code I have built only retrieves the first line of the table from Wikipedia. Looks like I am missing something insignificant. I would also like to Please help. See code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

    URL_TO = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
    response = requests.get(URL_TO)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    soup.prettify()

    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'}).tbody

    rows = table.find_all('tr')

    columns = [v.text.replace('\n', '') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

    for i in range(1, len(rows)):
        tds = rows[i].find_all('td')

        if len(tds) ==3:
            values= [tds[0].text.replace('\n',''), tds[1].text.replace('\n',''), tds[2].text.replace('\n','')]
        else:
            values = [td.text.replace('\n','') for td in tds]

    df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

    df.head()
```

Comment: The indent in your question is not right, but I would say that the problem is the indent in your original code, while it is not the best practice to use `df.append` like this, if you want your code to work, just indent `df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)` inside the loop `for` so same level than `tds = ...` for example

Comment: Sorry, edited the question and put the original imports in after the fact. This ended up indenting the rest of the code. Using a Jupyter notebook and the Panda and BeautifulSoup imports happen in previous cells. But thank you! The indent of the df.append (... portion of the code was all that was needed to get all rows! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `df.append()` within your iterations of the rows. Currently it goes through your iteration put doesn't append it.

Few other things:

1. Since you are iterating through a list, you don't need to create
   arange and use indexes. Just use `for row in rows:`
2. Instead of replacing `'\n'`, you can use `.strip()` to remove any
   white space. It'll take care of that, and any padded spaces
3. Why the if `tds == 3:` `else:` statements? Not needed
4. Since it's a `<table>` tag you are after, going with pandas
   `.read_html()`. It does all this work for you (using BeautifulSoup under the hood). See that code at below

So here's the edits made for your code. Again, the only thing that REALLY needed to be changed was the indentation of the `df.append`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL_TO = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
response = requests.get(URL_TO)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
soup.prettify()

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'}).tbody

rows = table.find_all('tr')

columns = [v.text.strip() for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

for row in rows:
    if row.find_all('td'):
        tds = row.find_all('td')
        values = [td.text.strip() for td in tds]
        df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
```

**SAME RESULT USING PANDAS:**

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```